# Derivative of function with 2 summations and powers

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm trying to compute the gradient of a complex loss function but I'm stuck on calculating the **derivative** of part of the expression,namely:

**with respect to $w_i$**

$$\sum_{n=1}^N(y^n -w_0 - \sum_{j=1}^p A_{nj}w_j)^2$$

A - design matrix;
w - vector; y - vector; $w_0$ - first element of w

*Edit*
Where it said k it should have been n - now fixed

Comment: How can $y$ be a vector? Should it be $y_n$ rather than $y^n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $i\in\{1,\ldots,p\}$:

$$\begin{align*}&\phantom{=}\ \, \frac{\partial}{\partial w_i}\sum_{n=1}^N\left[\left(y^n -w_0 - \sum_{j=1}^p A_{nj}w_j\right)^2\right]\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\partial}{\partial w_i}\left[\left(y^n -w_0 - \sum_{j=1}^p A_{nj}w_j\right)^2\right]\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^N\left[2\left(y^n -w_0 - \sum_{j=1}^p A_{nj}w_j\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial w_i}\left(y^n -w_0 - \sum_{j=1}^p A_{nj}w_j\right)\right]\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^N\left[2\left(y^n -w_0 - \sum_{j=1}^p A_{nj}w_j\right)\left( -\sum_{j=1}^p A_{nj}\frac{\partial w_j}{\partial w_i}\right)\right]\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^N\left[2\left(y^n -w_0 - \sum_{j=1}^p A_{nj}w_j\right)\left( - A_{ni}\right)\right]\\
&=-2\sum_{n=1}^N\left[A_{ni}\left(y^n -w_0 - \sum_{j=1}^p A_{nj}w_j\right)\right]
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I'm so sorry I just noticed my mistake where it sais k it should be n, will substituting it everywhere be sufficient?

Comment: Yes, it does not matter whether the upper limit of the sum is called $N$ or $K$.

Comment: I meant "k" as the index, sorry

Comment: Changing $k$ to $j$ in $A_{kj}$ just changes the last lines. I have updated my answer.